# Database data needed in integration tests; created by API calls or using imported data?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, integration-testing

This question is more or less programming language agnostic. However as I'm mostly into Java these days that's where I'll draw my examples from. I'm also thinking about the OOP case, so if you want to test a method you need an instance of that methods class.

A *core rule* for **[unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)** is that they should be autonomous, and that can be achieved by isolating a class from its dependencies. There are several ways to do it and it depends on if you inject your dependencies using [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) (in the Java world we have Spring, EJB3 and other frameworks/platforms which provide injection capabilities) and/or if you mock objects (for Java you have [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/) and [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/)) to separate a class being tested from its dependencies.

If we need to test groups of methods in different classes* and see that they are well integration, we write **[integration tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing)**. And here is my question!

- At least in web applications, state is often persisted to a database. We could use the same tools as for unit tests to achieve independence from the database. But in my humble opinion I think that there are cases when not using a database for integration tests is mocking too much (but feel free to disagree; not using a database at all, ever, is also a valid answer as it makes the question irrelevant).
- **When you use a database for integration tests, how do you fill that database with data?** I can see two approaches:

  - Store the database contents for the integration test and load it before starting the test. If it's stored as an SQL dump, a database file, XML or something else would be interesting to know.
  - Create the necessary database structures by API calls. These calls are probably split up into several methods in your test code and each of these methods *may* fail. It could be seen as your integration test having dependencies on other tests.

How are you making certain that database data needed for tests is there when you need it? And why did you choose the method you choose?

**Please provide an answer with a motivation**, as it's in the motivation the interesting part lies. Remember that just saying "It's best practice!" isn't a *real* motivation, it's just re-iterating something you've read or heard from someone. For that case please explain *why* it's best practice.

*I'm including one method calling other methods in (the same or other) instances of the same class in my definition of unit test, even though it might technically not be correct. Feel free to correct me, but let's keep it as a side issue.

Comment: I removed this same question which was posted as CW and now added it without CW. I got a helpful comment explaining that CW interferes with the reputation points system, so now it doesn't and you'll get all rewards you can get for answering! :-)

Comment: I'm starting a small bounty on this one as I would like more suggestions. Don't spare on the motivations! :-) When a week has passed I'll choose the top voted answer as my accepted answer, I'm voting too, but my vote is equal to yours.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I prefer creating the test data using API calls.

In the beginning of the test, you create an empty database (in-memory or the same that is used in production), run the install script to initialize it, and then create whatever test data used by the database. Creation of the test data may be organized for example with the [Object Mother](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ObjectMother.html) pattern, so that the same data can be reused in many tests, possibly with minor variations.

You want to have the database in a known state before every test, in order to have reproducable tests without side effects. So when a test ends, you should drop the test database or roll back the transaction, so that the next test could recreate the test data always the same way, regardless of whether the previous tests passed or failed.

The reason why I would avoid importing database dumps (or similar), is that it will couple the test data with the database schema. When the database schema changes, you would also need to change or recreate the test data, which may require manual work.

If the test data is specified in code, you will have the power of your IDE's refactoring tools at your hand. When you make a change which affects the database schema, it will probably also affect the API calls, so you will anyways need to refactor the code using the API. With nearly the same effort you can also refactor the creation of the test data - especially if the refactoring can be automated (renames, introducing parameters etc.). But if the tests rely on a database dump, you would need to manually refactor the database dump in addition to refactoring the code which uses the API.

Another thing related to integration testing the database, is testing that upgrading from a previous database schema works right. For that you might want to read the book [Refactoring Databases: Evolutionary Database Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321293533) or this article: http://martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html

Comment: Amazing answer. But With modern tools, don't you think that DDL and DML both can be easily changed? Jetbrains datagrip(for example) has great intellisense when it comes to writing queries. So if data model changes, you just change your schema.sql and then corresponding data.sql. Why use API(a programming language) to generate data when SQL is there to do it? Its like using wrong tool for the job. What do you think about this in modern times? Is it worth to spend time on API based test generation as opposed to simply writing sql files?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like your question is actually two questions. Should you exclude the database from your testing?  When you do a database, then how should you generate the data in the database?

When possible I prefer to use an actual database.  Frequently the queries (written in SQL, HQL, etc.)  in CRUD classes can return surprising results when confronted with an actual database.  It's better to flush these issues out early on.  Often developers will write very thin unit tests for CRUD; testing only the most benign cases.  Using an actual database for your testing can test all kinds corner cases you may not have even been aware of.

That being said there can be other issues.  After each test you want to return your database to a known state.  It my current job we nuke the database by executing all the DROP statements and then completely recreating all the tables from scratch.  This is extremely slow on Oracle, but can be very fast if you use an in memory database like HSQLDB.  When we need to flush out Oracle specific issues we just change the database URL and driver properties and then run against Oracle.  If you don't have this kind of database portability then Oracle also has some kind of database snapshot feature which can be used specifically for this purpose; rolling back the entire database to some previous state.  I'm sure what other databases have.

Depending on what kind of data will be in your database the API or the load approach may work better or worse.  When you have highly structured data with many relations, APIs will make your life easier by making the relations between your data explicit.  It will be harder for you to make a mistake when creating your test data set.  As mentioned by other posters refactoring tools can take care of some of the changes to structure of your data automatically.  Often I find it useful to think of API generated test data as composing a scenario; when a user/system has done steps X, Y Z and then tests will go from there.  These states can be achieved because you can write a program that calls the same API your user would use.

Loading data becomes much more important when you need large volumes of data, you have few relations between within your data or there is consistency in the data that can not be expressed using APIs or standard relational mechanisms.  At one job that at worked at my team was writing the reporting application for a large network packet inspection system.  The volume of data was quite large for the time.  In order to trigger a useful subset of test cases we really needed test data generated by the sniffers.  This way correlations between the information about one protocol would correlate with information about another protocol. It was difficult to capture this in the API.

Most databases have tools to import and export delimited text files of tables. But often you only want subsets of them; making using data dumps more complicated.  At my current job we need to take some dumps of actual data which gets generated by Matlab programs and stored in the database.  We have tool which can dump a subset of the database data and then compare it with the "ground truth" for testing.  It seems our extraction tools are being constantly modified.

Answer (score 5):

*Why are these two approaches defined as being exclusively?*

- I can't see any viable argument for
  *not* using pre-existing data sets, especially particular data that has
  caused problems in the past.
- I can't
  see any viable argument for *not*
  programmatically extending that data with
  all the possible conditions that
  you can imagine causing problems *and even a
  bit of random data for integration
  testing*.

In modern [agile approaches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development), Unit tests are where it really matters that the same tests are run each time. This is because unit tests are aimed not at finding bugs but at preserving the functionality of the app as it is developed, allowing the developer to refactor as needed.

Integration tests, on the other hand, are designed to find the bugs you did not expect.  Running with *some* different data each time can even be good, in my opinion. You just have to make sure your test preserves the failing data if you get a failure. Remember, in formal integration testing, the application itself will be frozen except for bug fixes so your tests can be change to test for the maximum possible number and kinds of bugs. In integration, you can and should throw the kitchen sink at the app.

As others have noted, of course, all this naturally depends on the kind of application that you are developing and the kind of organization you are in, etc.

Answer (score 5):

In integration tests, you need to test with real database, as you have to verify that your application can actually talk to the database. Isolating the database as dependency means that you are postponing the real test of whether your database was deployed properly, your schema is as expected and your app is configured with the right connection string. You don't want to find any problems with these when you deploy to production.

You also want to test with both precreated data sets and empty data set. You need to test both path where your app starts with an empty database with only your default initial data and starts creating and populating the data and also with a well-defined data sets that target specific conditions you want to test, like stress, performance and so on.

Also, make sur that you have the database in a well-known state before each state. You don't want to have dependencies between your integration tests.

Comment: I wouldn't say this answers the question. OP was specific in asking what would be the decision between creating the state in the DB with API calls or using imported data (like DB dumps). This answer doesn't touch on that.

Answer (score 4):

I've used [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) to take snapshots of records in a database and store them in XML format. Then my unit tests (we called them integration tests when they required a database), can wipe and restore from the XML file at the start of each test.

I'm undecided whether this is worth the effort. One problem is dependencies on other tables. We left static reference tables alone, and built some tools to detect and extract all child tables along with the requested records. I read someone's recommendation to disable all foreign keys in your integration test database. That would make it way easier to prepare the data, but you're no longer checking for any referential integrity problems in your tests.

Another problem is database schema changes. We wrote some tools that would add default values for columns that had been added since the snapshots were taken.

Obviously these tests were **way slower** than pure unit tests.

When you're trying to test some legacy code where it's very difficult to write unit tests for individual classes, this approach may be worth the effort.

Answer (score 3):

I do both, depending on what I need to test:

- I import static test data from SQL scripts or DB dumps. This data is used in object load (deserialization or object mapping) and in SQL query tests (when I want to know whether the code will return the correct result).

  Plus, I usually have some backbone data (config, value to name lookup tables, etc). These are also loaded in this step. Note that this loading is a single test (along with creating the DB from scratch).
- When I have code which modifies the DB (object -> DB), I usually run it against a living DB (in memory or a test instance somewhere). This is to ensure that the code works; not to create any large amount of rows. After the test, I rollback the transaction (following the rule that tests must not modify the global state).

Of course, there are exceptions to the rule:

- I also create large amount of rows in performance tests.
- Sometimes, I have to commit the result of a unit test (otherwise, the test would grow too big).

Answer (score 2):

I generally use SQL scripts to fill the data in the scenario you discuss.

It's straight-forward and very easily repeatable.

Comment: But when the entities change you have to change the data in your SQL scripts as well. How come that has not been a problem for you?

Comment: I'm using an in-memory database SQL Lite. Propel ORM for PHP allows you to dump the schema and data. I just make two calls in my test and it creates the database and imports a fresh set of data from the previously exported file. Exporting the dump takes less than 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not answer all your questions, if any, but I made the decision in one project to do unit testing against the DB. I felt in my case that the DB structure needed testing too, i.e. did my DB design deliver what is needed for the application. Later in the project when I feel the DB structure is stable, I will probably move away from this.

To generate data I decided to create an external application that filled the DB with "random" data, I created a person-name and company-name generators etc.

The reason for doing this in an external program was:
1. I could rerun the tests on by test modified data, i.e. making sure my tests were able to run several times and the data modification made by the tests were valid modifications.
2. I could if needed, clean the DB and get a fresh start.

I agree that there are points of failure in this approach, but in my case since e.g. person generation was part of the business logic generating data for tests was actually testing that part too.

Answer (score 0):

Our team confront the same question recently.

Before, we were using specflow to do integration testing. With specflow, QA can write each test case inside which populating necessary test data to DB.

Now, QA want to use postman to test API, how can they populate the data? One solution is creating Apis for populating them. Another is sync historical data from Prod to test env.

Will update my answer once we try different solutions and decide which one to go.

Comment: Any updates after trying the solutions?

Comment: We decided to use api to create test data. 
Now, we have switched to snowflakes which is easier to copy a proc env